# Call SOAP web-service using Windows proxy settings in Java

Tags: java, web-services, https, proxy

I'm writing a standalone java app.
I have to use default system (Windows XP, 7) proxy settings to call the SOAP web-services using HTTPS protocol.

To determine system proxy settings I use the ProxySelector class. Here's the code:

```
System.setProperty("java.net.useSystemProxies", "true");
List proxies = ProxySelector.getDefault().select(new URI("https://www.google.com/"));
for (Iterator iter = proxies.iterator(); iter.hasNext();) {
    Proxy proxy = (Proxy) iter.next();
    InetSocketAddress address = (InetSocketAddress) proxy.address();
    if (address == null) {
        UTLogger.getLogger().debug("No proxy (direct connection)");
    } else {
        if (proxy.type().equals(Proxy.Type.HTTP)) {
            System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", address.getHostName());
            System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", String.valueOf(address.getPort()));
            System.setProperty("https.proxyHost", address.getHostName());
            System.setProperty("https.proxyPort", String.valueOf(address.getPort()));
        } else if (proxy.type().equals(Proxy.Type.SOCKS)) {
            System.setProperty("socksProxyHost", address.getHostName());
            System.setProperty("socksProxyPort", String.valueOf(address.getPort()));
        }
    }
}
System.setProperty("java.net.useSystemProxies", "false");
```

And here's how I initialize connection:

```
SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
sc.init(null, new TrustManager[]{new TrustDummy()}, new SecureRandom());
HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sc.getSocketFactory());
servicePort = new MyPort(new URL(wsdlLocation), new QName(nameSpaceURI, localPart)).getMyPortSoap();
```

I don't understand why there is no `Proxy.Type.HTTPS`? If i call a web-service method i get the following errors.

With http proxy set:

```
javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: Failed to access the WSDL at: ht tps://...?wsdl. It failed with: Got Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection? while opening stream from ht tps://...?wsdl.
```

and with https proxy set:

```
javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: Failed to access the WSDL at: ht tps://...?wsdl. It failed with: Got Unable to tunnel through proxy. Proxy returns "HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden" while opening stream from ht tps://...?wsdl.
```

Am I doing it wrong?